Training an image classifier to detect slight differences in line angles
I've been struggling to find success training a Yolov8 classifier to detect slight difference in line angles.
My hunch is that the difference in line angles are so slight that the classifier is struggling to make a distinction. Some evidence to corroborate this hunch is that the top-1 accuracy is a measly 0.66, while the top-5 accuracy is 1.
The training data more or less looks like this:




The original data separates the angles by increments of 0.01. So 0.01,0.02,0.03 all qualify as different angles. I knew the classifier would struggle with this level of specificity, so I simplified it a bit grouped my data into buckets: 0.0-0.1, 0.1-0.2, and 0.2-0.3 all the way up to 1.5-1.6, leaving me with 11 classes.
Although the buckets exist and add a feasible structure to the model, the actual specificity in the data still exists. To illustrate this point, the two following images look almost identical, but belong to separate classes.


The fact that the human eye cannot easily discern which line is steeper makes me skeptical that the model will be able to reliably do so.
One thing to note is that I've not included a background class in the training data. The reason for this is that the model will only ever be used under very specific conditions where there will be minimal background.
Last thing - Here is a confusion matrix from the training output.


Have you considered pre-processing your images with the Hough transform? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform Performing classification in the Hough space (possibly using a simpler linear classifier) could be easier.
